# PyQt: Sending multiple strings to printer

Tags: python, sqlite, printing, pyqt

my application is coming up nicely, with all the problems I’ve asked help for it better be :) Last thing I wanted to make is the ability to print (or make a report) various strings queried from database. I googled a lot, found ReportLab Toolkit, reStructuredText and more, but that is not what I am looking for.

Here is my code: (indentation might be slightly off because of pasting)

```
def preparePrint(self):
 caseNumber = (str(self.ui.linecaseNumber.text()).upper())
 if caseNumber:
  with con:
   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.execute('SELECT notes FROM cases WHERE caseNumber =?',[caseNumber])
   tempnotes=str(cur.fetchone())
   cur.execute('SELECT name FROM cases WHERE caseNumber =?',[caseNumber])
   tempname=str(cur.fetchone())
   cur.execute('SELECT date FROM cases WHERE caseNumber =?',[caseNumber])
   tempdate = str(cur.fetchone()) #fetch 3 values from SQLite database

    #get rid of "tuple marks"
   tempname = (str(tempname.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',','').replace("'","")))
   tempnotes = (str(tempnotes.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',','').replace("'",""))) 
   tempdate=(str(tempdate.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',','').replace("'",""))) 

    #join them in one string. Notice the \n
   finalText = (str("NAME: %s\nDATE: %s\nNOTES: %s" %(tempname,tempdate,tempnotes))) 

#put the joined string into one QTextEdit, while preserving HTML properties (bold mostly).
   self.ui.textPrint.setHtml(str(finalText.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',','').replace("'","").replace('\\n','\r')))
```

After this function, there is one for creating PDF which works EXCEPT newline characters. When I print *finalText* to console it looks the way I want it to. It does not look like that in QTextEdit :(

Console output:

```
Name: Some Name
Date: 14.07.2012
Notes: Some notes go here
```

QTextEdit and PDF output:

```
Name: Some Name Date: 14.07.2012 Notes: Some notes go here
```

Comment: try `\r\n` instead of only `\n`

Comment: In _finalText_ ? It does the same, no line break.

Comment: Why are you using `.replace('\\n','\r')` at the very end? Remove it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

This code is wrong in so many places...
I modified your code with many improvements and proper line length:

```
def preparePrint(self):
    caseNumber = str(self.ui.linecaseNumber.text()).upper()
    if caseNumber:
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            # fetch 3 values from SQLite database
            cur.execute('SELECT notes FROM cases WHERE caseNumber = ?',
                        caseNumber)
            tempnotes = cur.fetchone()[0]
            # if you have multiple columns, use:
            # tempnotes = ''.join(cur.fetchone())
            cur.execute('SELECT name FROM cases WHERE caseNumber = ?',
                        caseNumber)
            tempname = cur.fetchone()[0]
            cur.execute('SELECT date FROM cases WHERE caseNumber = ?',
                        caseNumber)
            tempdate = cur.fetchone()[0]

        # no need to 'get rid of "tuple marks"',
        # because they aren't there now

        # join them in one string. Notice the \n
        finalText = ("NAME: %s\nDATE: %s\nNOTES: %s"
                     % (tempname, tempdate, tempnotes))

        # put the joined string into one QTextEdit, 
        # while preserving HTML properties (bold mostly).

        # again, no need to 'get rid of "tuple marks"'
        self.ui.textPrint.setHtml(finaltext)
```

This should make the text with line breaks. If not, then try using `\r\n` in finaltext instead of `\n`. If it still doesn't work then, then something strange is going, but at least you have nicer code then.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My code is most probably bad, I'm self-taught beginner. However, your code does not work properly.

SQLite complains about queries, with error "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied."

Query that works (maybe bad, but works) is:

`cur.execute('SELECT notes FROM cases WHERE caseNumber = ?',
                        [caseNumber])`

I don't mean to be disrespectful and I really appreciate your comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

I cracked it! :D
Since QTextEdit accepts HTML, < br > tag will make a newline. Here is a piece of code that is different from original post:

```
finalText = (str("NAME: %s%sDATE: %s%sNOTES: %s%s" %(tempname,'<br>',tempdate,'<br>',tempnotes,'<br>')))
self.ui.textPrint.setHtml(str(finalText).replace('\\n','\r'))
```